# Why im getting this error Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null. Dart Language

Tags: flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety, null-safety

so i was learning about SWITCH and CASE Statements in dart language, in the course he explains the code but he don't get an error while i get one.

the error i get
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
String ``userName = name ?? "Guest User";

My Code is

```
void learnCondExpr() {
 String name = 'Yamix';
    
 String userName = name ?? "Guest User";
 print(userName);
}
```

can i get some help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart, by default, will assume any variable you've declared **can never be null**. You won't be able to assign `null` to a variable, and at runtime it will throw an error. It will also complain if you try to treat a non-nullable variable like it *could* be null, which is what you're doing with '??'.

You can use the `?` after a variable's type to tell Dart that your variable will accept null values. `??` allows us to handle null values without writing extra lines of code

In short, `x = y ?? z` can be described as

If the **left operand** (y) is `null`, then assign the **right operand** (z) ie.

```
void example(String? myString) {
  String? y = myString;
  String z = 'spam';

  var x = y ?? z;
  print(x);
}

void main() {
  example('hello!');
  example(null);
}

// Output:
// hello!
// spam
```

Notice that I've added '?' after 'String' on the 2nd line, letting Dart know that 'y' could be null. This prevents me getting an error later in the code where I try to use a null-aware operator (??) to assign it to 'x'.

I hope this helped give you some background beyond just resolving your issue! :)

[Short medium article on Null-aware operators in Dart](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb)

Comment: Yes this one was helpful, i see that name is allowed to be null if there is no input give it GuestUser, Thanks for the help i really appreciate it <3 .

Comment: the same idea that I got from the course but with the wrong code, I think the course is 3 years old should I just change it or follow the same course & dart doc.

Answer (score 0):

So `??` operation must be put after a nullable variable.
But in your code `name` variable is `String`, not nullable.
So `?? "Guest User"` is always ignored.
The warning is saying about that - this code is useless.

P.S.
If you fix code to `String? name = 'Yamix';`, the warning will go away.

Answer (score 0):

The probem is that `name` is not-nullable String.
You can declare it as a `nullable` type by adding a `?`.

Like this:

```
String? name = 'Yamix';
```

Keep in mind that even if your string is nullable but you assign a value to it, that's going to be constant, and that's the reason why you may be getting a warning when checking it for `null`:

> The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed.
> Try removing the operator and the right operand

Comment: i get it now, but still getting that same error when i give it the value of 'Yamix'.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `?` token after `String` Keyword:

```
void learnCondExpr() {
    String? name = 'Yamix';

    String userName = name ?? "Guest User";
    print(userName);
}
```

This will work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer! However, this solution is already covered by the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71078531/12567365): "_You can use the ? after a variable's type_". That answer also provides more discussion/explanation than your answer.